# Get Function not implemented error when using ssi's and using window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

I get an error message `Error Message: Not implemented` When doing this and using this statement in a server side include.

```
window.onload=readInSubsystemInformationFromFile();
```

It works however if I click `ok button` on that error message, its just annoying that this error message pops up.

So my question to you is, are there a function that checks if `readInSubsystemInformationFromFile()` has been initialized? If so do this method (In other words it shall be of the type onLoad) If not, then wait until it is ready.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

To check if the function has been defined yet:

```
if(typeof readInSubsystemInformationFromFile == 'function'){
    // Exists
    readInSubsystemInformationFromFile();
}
```

Also, try jQuery for it's onload method... Works in pretty much all browsers and works well. It's a hard thing to get right.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/